# AngularJS - ng-click in shell page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an Angular JS app in which the header and footer are part of index.html, and the views are loaded dynamically between. I have a `signOut()` function on the scope in my controllers that makes the proper calls to a REST API to sign out the user. However, the "Sign Out" button is a part of the header, so I'm having trouble getting it to call the `signOut()` function.

`ng-click="signOut()"` inside the `<button>` tag does absolutely nothing, presumably because the button is in the shell page, not one of the views, and so doesn't have access to the scope.

Alternatively to using `ng-click`, I tried putting some code in my view to call the `signOut()` function when the button is clicked, since I know I can access it through the DOM. I first tried this:

```
<script>
    $('#logoutbutton').on('click', function(){
        {{signOut()}};
        console.log("signout clicked");
    });
</script>
```

But that throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: signOut is not defined` because the scope apparently isn't accessible within the `<script></script>` tags. For that same reason, I suspect

```
<script>
    $('#logoutbutton').on('click', 
            {{signOut()}}
            );
</script>
```

would not work, even though trying to use that code throws a syntax error (`Unexpected token '{'`).

**I'm trying to find out if there's any way I can call the signOut() function when the logout button is clicked without needing to make the button a part of the view instead of the shell page.**

For the curious, I control whether the button is visible by setting `display:none` by default, and putting this line at the top of all the views where I want it to be displayed:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('logoutbutton').style.display = 'block';
</script>
```

which is how I know I can access the button through the DOM, even inside the views.

Comment: try saying `$('#logoutbutton').on('click', $scope.signOut);`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There are two snippets that use that.

Comment: can you add a plunker for this?

Comment: You could just put a controller on your index page, eg. <body ng-controller="MasterCtrl"> - your signOut() function can then be defined in this controller and all of your view controllers will become child controllers of this.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/nglO4r Five minute stripped-down attempt; doesn't necessarily work but should at least show how the files fit together if you're familiar with Angular.

Comment: Is your button inside you ng-app container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
<button id="btn">click</button>

$scope.show = function(){alert('msg');}
$('#btn').on('click',$scope.show);
```

Comment: You should not presumably give suggestions based on off-frameworks. It is jQuery and definitely not a good suggestion at all.

Comment: This _almost_ works. For me, Putting this line in the controller causes the function to run not when the button is clicked, but each time the view is initialized.

Comment: **Update:** The form above doesn't work, but when I replace $scope.show with an anonymous function that calls $scope.show, it works as expected.

Comment: `$scope.show = function(){alert('msg');}

$('#btn').on('click',function(){

    $scope.show();

});`

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with Mostafa Talebi the accepted answer is using a completely different framework and isn't an AngularJS based answer. In fact the only problem I can see with your plunkr is that the main div is missing the ng-controller directive which would need to point at your sign out controller. You would then be able to hook up an ng-click on your button to your sign out function in the regular way. This is essentially what glendaviesnz is suggesting. You wouldn't then need to do the javascript get element and event listening which really isn't the Angular way.

Further to this the use of jquery events in an angular app should be avoided because effectively they happen outside the view of angular or more precisely outside of the angular digest cycle. You can use the $on to list for events in Angular and $broadcast/$emit to broadcast events.

Your requirement is a basic spa with authentication and there are any number of good examples of this Dan Wahlin's CustomerManager springs to mind which demonstrates how to achieve what you want in a purely Angular way.